# phpactiverecords - not equal to

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

How to add a not equal condition in phpactiverecords?

```
Code_reference::find('all', array('code' => $name), array('conditions' => 'id != '.$code_id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `<>`

```
Code_reference::find('all', array('code' => $name), array('conditions' => 'id <> '.$code_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the second `$options` array will get ignored. You have to merge them yourself and thus cannot use the compact *hash*-mode anymore.

```
CodeReference::all(array('code = ? AND id != ?', $name, $code_id));
```

To print the SQL query, you can use `last_sql`.

```
CodeReference::table()->last_sql
```

For more details, please refer to the official (but yet laggy) documentation:

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders#conditions